# View of all PHP functions and classes in entire Project

Tags: php, class, view, window, outline

New to using Aptana so I'm not sure if this is possible or not.

I would like a view window which shows all the PHP function and class definitions for the entire project.
I am already aware that the Outline window provides class and function definitions for the script actively being edited (one PHP file at a time).  But I want to know if it is possible to have a window that keeps all the function and class defs indexed similarly for the whole project.  Some times I remember the name of the class or function I am hunting for but don't remember which PHP script it's in.  I would like to be able to see an aphebetically sorted window that I could simply click the class or function def and it will pop open the correct .php file for editing.

Can this be done with the core or with plugin?

Answer (score -1):

```
$all=get_defined_functions();
var_dump($all['user']);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-functions.php

```
foreach ($all['user'] as $name) {
    $reflFunc = new ReflectionFunction($name);
    print $reflFunc->getFileName() . ':' . $reflFunc->getStartLine();
}
```

Comment: Maybe the question is off topic but they are asking about the Aptana IDE.

Comment: Rather than rely on the IDE, It may be beneficial to do it with php, in any IDE.

Comment: I was requesting via IDE.  For two reasons...
1) If I'm debugging a problematic script, the above function won't work.
2) That only returns defined functions, classes would need another solution.